# Cross-sectional moments

Tags: risk, forecasting, distribution

I got a seminar topic named Forecasting risk from cross sectional moments? Could at least someone tell me what should I write about and if there is any paper that I could read. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I am not sure what "cross sectional moment mean"? Are you sure it is not "second central moment"?

Comment: I haven't the faintest either, this topic is actually the top hit for '"Cross-sectional moments"' on Google in incognito mode for me. @user17539, can you please clarify?

Comment: Look up "cross sectional standard deviation" or "cross sectional dispersion". It is a measure of how the population of stocks stocks did on a particular day. (all stocks up or all stocks down => dispersion of zero.